# Solving a project in Python / pygame

Tags: python

I am solving an issue in Python and Pygame (of which I have little knowledge). I am trying to find the way for finding the column x in a 2d rectangular board. I know that to find row y, I would go by:

```
ind = y * self._num_cols
    return self._grid[ind : ind + self._num_cols]
```

How do I find column x then, without using numPy?

Comment: What do you mean by finding column `x`? What is it you're looking for? Are you asking how to get any column `x`? Then it should be to just index it directly `self._grid[ind : ind + self._num_cols][x]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that it is 1 dimensional, you can do:

```
return [self._grid[x + i*self._num_cols] for i in range(self._num_cols)]
```

I know it seems long, but it is just iteratively getting the one in that column for each row.